# Generate a subset without disturbing the order

Tags: subset

Given a set of letters S = { a, b, c, d, e}

How do I generate the following subsets if the input  k = 3?

abc
abd
abe
acd
ace
ade
bcd
bce
bde
cde

Where the subsets does not violate the order of the letters as in S. 
What is the name for such problem, and what is the solutions?

Comment: That's not too difficult using recursion. What have you tried?

Comment: I cannot come up with any convincing algorithm. I have search the net, but I cannot get the proper algorithm. What is the name for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider a binary string having 5 places (or as many places as there are characters in S) consisting of k 1's and (|S|-k) 0's.
2. Generate all (|S|! / (k! * (|S|-k)!)) permutations of the above strings.
3. Now output characters corresponding to 1's. That will not violate the order of the characters in S.